# Scripting Terminal Command with Automator

Tags: terminal, keyboard, automator, script

I am trying to automate a set of terminal commands. I was given the below instructions and manually doing it works just fine, but I wanted to know if there was a way to use the Mac "Automator" on my Mac to make a script/batch so all I have to do is click on it to apply all of these no matter what computer I want to run it on. Is that possible? (see below)

---

If the error persists, please try running these commands at the terminal to see if that corrects the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>eicar</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
        <string>limit</string>
        <string>maxfiles</string>
        <string>16384</string>
        <string>16384</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

- Launch Terminal
- Type `sudo su` then enter your password to log in as root
- Type `vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.launchd.limit.plist`
- When in the vi editor, press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode then paste the exact code content above (<kbd>Cmd-V</kbd>). This will force the limit to 16384 files per process and 16384 files total
- Save your file and quit using <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>:wq</kbd>
- Reboot your system, and check that it is working using the command `launchctl limit`

Comment: It might be easier to edit this once (on one Mac) and then copy the whole file to all other computers involved.

Comment: Terminal, sudo commands, vi editor, masks a very easy task. You need just create a file with name `com.apple.launchd.limit.plist` and copy and paste to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` folder in `finder`. Anyway I'll show how to create this in `Automator`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Automator task that can help you with.

**1. Action: Get text**
To do: Copy and paste desired text content.

[image: First action]

**2. Action: New text file**
To do: File format 'simple text'; save as 'automatortempfile.txt'; In `Where` is tricky, when you click will show a select folder location, press <kbd>Cmd+Shift+g</kbd> and type `/var/tmp`.

[image: Second action]

**3. Action: Execute Applescript**
To do: Copy and paste this content.

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate
    return text returned of (display dialog "Enter password" default answer "" with hidden answer)
end tell
```

This will open a dialog with a message "Enter password", that you must provide user password (this user must have admin rights, because this is required to write in `/Library/*` folder).

[image: Third action]

**4. Action: Execute shell script**
To do: Copy and paste this content.

```
sudo -S mkdir -p /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo -S mv /var/tmp/automatortempfile.txt /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.launchd.limit.plist
```

First line: Create a folder `LaunchDeamons` if doesn't exist (just for ensure that folder exists).
Second Line: Move your created file `automatortempfile.txt` from `/var/tmp` folder to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and rename it to `com.apple.launchd.limit.plist`.

`sudo -S` will read password from stdin.

[image: Fourth action]

**Now, just save and use!**